# find the associated matrix with respect to change in basis under identity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> In each following cases, find $M_{B'}^B(id)$. The vector space in each case is $\Bbb R^3$
>   1) $B = \{ ( 1,1,0), (-1,1,1 ), (0,1,2 )\}$
>      $\;\;\;B' = \{ (2,1,1),(0,1,1), (-1,1,1)\}$
>   2) $B = \{ ( 3,2,1), (0,-2,5), (1,1,2)\}$
>      $\;\;\;B' = \{ (1,1,0),(-1,2,4), (2,-1,1)\}$

Here $id$ is identity mapping. Since there was no example of this problem (this is from `Linear Algebra - Serge Lang (Chapter VI section 3)`, I am confused how to do it. A solution of either of one or an example or links to it would suffice.

Comment: Take the first vector of the initial basis. Express it as a linear combination of the final basis. The coefficients of the linear combination constitute your first column (respect the order). Continue with the second vector of the initial basis...

Comment: you mean $(1,1,0) = a(2,1,1)+b(0,1,1)+c(−1,1,1)$ and solve for $a,b,c$

Comment: If the notation $M_{B'}^B$ means that the initial basis is $B$ and the final one is $B'$, then yes. I don't have Lang with me, so I don't know his convention. I am used to another one which would see $B'$ as the initial basis.

Comment: yes!! that is the convention as you described. here is a [link to lang](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgonzaloandres.ublog.cl%2Farchivos%2F13543%2Flinear_algebra.pdf&ei=PmsSUYq_McfsrAfag4DoDA&usg=AFQjCNF2453gMS7xH-OEhiCcSHVpu-KJ3g&sig2=iZjrmD1KhlIzHEezPPK2gQ&bvm=bv.41934586,d.bmk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do was noted by @julien. I am writing some notation just to clear the point. Let $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ is a basis for a vector space $V$, and $\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\}$ be anothe basis for the vector space. Moreover assume that we can write each $f_i$ as a linear combination of $\{e_i\}_{i=1..n}$. I mean: $$f_1=a_{11}e_1+...+a_{1n}e_n\\f_2=a_{21}e_1+...+a_{2n}e_n\\.\\.\\.\\\\f_n=a_{n1}e_1+...+a_{nn}e_n$$ wherein $a_{ij}\in K$ our field. Therefore the *transpose* of the matrix: $$P=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ...& a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & ...& a_{2n} \\.\\.\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ...& a_{nn} \end{array} \right)$$ is called the transition matrix from the basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1..n}$ to a new basis $\{f_i\}_{i=1..n}$. Note that since $\{f_i\}_{i=1..n}$ are independent so $P^{-1}$ is invertible.

Comment: thanks you too!! I didn't know it was that simple :)

Comment: @testuser: I am inly glad of making some points clearer for you.

Comment: Actually, now I realize that the procedure I described is not the fastest one, since it boils down to inverting the same matrix three times...

Comment: @julien: I know what you noted. In fact we would have some systems which should be solved. I mean the OP's second comment.

Comment: All the systems $AX=Y$ have the same coefficients $A$, so it is more efficient to find the inverse of $A$ than to solve the $n$ systems separately.

Comment: Very efficient, and spot-on!+

Comment: @amWhy Don't you agree with my comment above?

Answer (score 3):

The procedure I described in my comment is actually not the most efficient one, since it makes you invert the same matrix three times...

Let us suppose we work with bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $B=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $B'=\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$. 
Now let us introduce the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $B_0=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$.

By Theorem 3.4 in Lang, we have
$$
M_{B'}^B(id)=M_{B'}^{B_0}(id)M_{B_0}^B(id).
$$
And by Corollary 3.5, $M_{B'}^{B_0}(id)=M_{B_0}^{B'}(id)^{-1}$, so 
$$
M_{B'}^B(id)=M_{B_0}^{B'}(id)^{-1}M_{B_0}^B(id).
$$

Now observe that $M_{B_0}^B(id)$ (respectively $M_{B_0}^{B'}(id)$) is simply the matrix whose columns are the vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ (resp. $y_1,\ldots,y_n$) with coordinates as they are given, namely in the canonical basis.

So all you have to is to invert once and for all $M_{B_0}^{B'}(id)$, and then multiply the two matrices.